# Override stacking in bootstrap using horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am using using bootstrap in combination with bootstrap-horizon for a horizontal display of images. Ideally, I would like the images to remain scrolling horizontally on desktop and tablets, and then change to vertically stacked singular images on mobile. However, the images begin to stack sooner than I desire at intermediate screen widths.

```
<div class="DocumentList">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1 DocumentItem">
    <br>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x600?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    <br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 DocumentItem">
    <br>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x600?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    <br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 DocumentItem">
    <br>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x600?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    <br><br>
</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 DocumentItem">
    <br>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x600?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    <br><br>
</div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 DocumentItem">
    <br>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x600?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    <br><br>
</div>
```

....these just repeat as filler.

And the .css for the horizon is:

```
.DocumentList{
overflow-x:scroll;;
overflow-y:hidden;
padding: 20px;
height: auto;
white-space:nowrap;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}

.row {
width: 400%;
}

.rowsmall {
width:50%;
}

.DocumentItem{
border:1px solid black;
padding:50px;
height:auto;
width: 400px;
}
```

The output looks like:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 .... (On desktop - OK)

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
 (At intermediate sizes - This is what I want to change...I would like this to continue scrolling horizontally)

1
2
3
4
... (On mobile - OK)

Comment: are referring to something like this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/1v2th943)